# Eclipse 3.7.0 Indigo CDT, symbol vector could not be resolved

Tags: ubuntu, linker, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-indigo

This might very well be similar if not the same to question that has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980186/error-symbol-vector-could-not-be-resolved). I am running eclipse CDT on ubuntu machine. I get false compilation error saying 'vector' symbol could not be resolved. 
I have tried to fix it by manually looking for vector file location with the following command:`find /usr/include/ -name vector -print`
This lists the location of vector in my machine as `/usr/include/c++/4.5/vector`
I manually add it to the GNU C++ include directory by going to 
`project properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols ->GNUC++->Add` and add the location but to no avail. I also tried adding other paths as suggested in one of the comments in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962655/eclipse-3-7-0-indigo-with-cdt-shows-many-false-compilation-errors) by Catskul.
I am pretty sure its the linker issue, the tool chain I use is the default Linux gcc, have also tried the cross gcc tool chain. And yes I `#include <vector>` and include `using namespace std` as well. Also intellisense popup did not have vector when I typed `std::`. F3 on `#include<vector>` took me to the source.
Any help in this issue is appreciated.

**Edit 2:** Well I had to do a fresh install of eclipse to make it work. I had tested the same application in another system, worked like a charm, so I went for an easy fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved)

Answer (score 3):

I meet a similar error, and I find the answer from website  [error , Symbol 'vector' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980186/error-symbol-vector-could-not-be-resolved) .
You can do this:
In Eclipse, right-click on the project name...Select Index...Rebuild.And the you clean and build the project.

Comment: Index rebuild does not help in my case. Thanks for the link though appreciate the help.